# Click inside the Path in Openstreetmap

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have two overlays in my openstreetmap app, Itemized overlay and Path overlay together. I want to provide click inside the path inside the path overlay and custom marker

Comment: You forgot to mention your framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got answer for the Above question...

Add all path overlays into a single layer.

In on single tap check isPointOnLine(lox,loy,ltx,lty,  x, y)

```
public boolean isPointOnLine(double lox, double loy, double ltx,
        double lty, double x, double y) {
    // determine if point is on line
    Double dx = x - lox;
    Double dy = y - loy;
    Double tx = ltx - lox;
    Double ty = lty - loy;

    // normalise the line vector
    Double t1 = new Double(1 / Math.sqrt(tx * tx + ty * ty));

    tx *= t1;
    ty *= t1;

    // calculate inverse length of secondary vector
    Double dl = new Double(1 / Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));

    // take dot product of normalised line vector, and rotated normalised
    // secondary vector
    Double dot = (dy * tx - dx * ty) * dl;
    // Increase these values for less or more picky
    if (dot < -0.2 || dot > 0.2)
        return false;

    // calculate distance along line segment by taking dot product of
    // normalised
    // line vector and un-normalised secondary vector
    Double dis = tx * dx + ty * dy;
    if (dis < 0 || dis > 1 / t1)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not available with PathOverlay. 
Use [OSMBonusPack Polyline](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/).

If you just want to open a bubble, use setInfoWindow.

If you want to do something else, inherit from Polyline class, override onSingleTapConfirmed, and use isCloseTo.